# Recorrer una lista alineando los items a izquierda o derecha en función de su paridad

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de modificar un componente existente dentro de una aplicación, la idea es que se recorre una única lista de elementos, estos elementos tienen un campo posición, cuando la posición es impar el elemento debe aparecer a la izquierda y cuando es par a la derecha. Lo explico con un trozo de código lo mas simple posible para que se entienda fácil.

```
<div class="container">
   while(!lista.isEmpty()){
     <div class="c-box if(posicion%2 == 0){'c-right'}else{'c-left'}">{{item}}</div>
   }
</div>
```

El problema es que no siempre hay los mismos elementos en ambas columnas por lo que la solución mas obvia que sería:

```css
.container{
}
.c-box{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.c-left{
    float:left;
}
.c-right{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-box c-left">1-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">2-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">3-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">4-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">5-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">6-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">7-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">8-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">9-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">10-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">11-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">12-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">13-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">14-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">15-Right</div>
</div>
```

No funciona ya que cuando se encadenan varios elementos impares los va poniendo uno al lado del otro debido al `float`.

Otra solución que he probado es la de asignar un margen lateral para forzar la posición a izquierda y derecha pero en este caso queda un gap a izquierda o derecha de cada uno de los campos:

```css
.container{
    }
.c-box{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.c-left{
    float:left;
    margin-right:50%;
}
.c-right{
    float:right;
    margin-left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-box c-left">1-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">2-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">3-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">4-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">5-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">6-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">7-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">8-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">9-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">10-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">11-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">12-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">13-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">14-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">15-Right</div>
</div>
```

Esta solución queda como se muestra en esta imagen:
[image: resultado]

Sé que utilizando 2 `divs` con dos columnas y recorriendo la lista dos veces este problema estaría solucionado pero no me es posible aplicar esa solución en este caso, la lista debe de recorrerse tal como aparece en el primer código, si que tengo la posibilidad de usar `flex-box` o cualquier solución `CSS` pero he realizado multitud de intentos sin ningún resultado.

**UPDATE:** Hay un problema con la solución con grid cuando la aplico al caso real, que viene de que no he sabido explicar bien el problema, olvidé especificar que la altura de estos items puede ser variable ya que algunos de ellos despliegan otros campos en función de su valor, como se ve en la siguiente imagen.

[image: problema]

Esto hace que cuando un campo de la izquierda despliega otros campos se desplace todas las columnas de la derecha y se genere un gap vacío en la columna opuesta.

Gracias de antemano, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Podrías usar `grid`? ¿O como mucho solamente `flex-box`?

Comment: En principio podría user grid también, no habría problema

Comment: ¿Podrias añadir a la pregunta el código html generado por el servidor? Es decir el que ves tu desde el navegador sin el bucle.

Comment: Por supuesto, ahí lo añado, lo he limpiado un poco para que se vea mejor, estos divs llevan contenido en el resultado real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El sistema de `grid` es muy potente y te permite hacer cosas "muy locas" si te pones a pelearte un rato con él:

- A través de `grid-template-columns` establecí que los *items* se posicionaran simulando dos columnas.
- Con `grid-column-start` establecí que las columnas **pares** se colocaran en la segunda columna y los **impares** en la primera.

Esto ocasionaba que quedasen huecos cuando coincidían dos columnas con la misma alineación seguidas. Así que con `grid-auto-flow` delegué la tarea de eliminar estos huecos al algoritmo mágico de colocación de **grid** que muy educadamente eliminó los huecos dejados.

```css
.contenedor {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 45%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.par {
 grid-column-start: 2;
}

.impar {
  grid-column-start: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item impar">
    <p>Impar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item impar">
    <p>Impar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item impar">
    <p>Impar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He aceptado esta solución porque en realidad responde perfectamente a la pregunta pero hay un problema con esta solución cuando la aplico al caso real, que viene de que no he sabido explicar bien el problema, se me olvidó decir que  la altura de estos items puede ser variable ya que algunos de ellos despliegan otros campos en función de su valor. Amplío la pregunta añadiendo una imagen para que se entienda lo que digo.

Comment: Te pido disculpas por desaceptar esta respuesta de momento, lo hago para que mas gente pueda aportar, aunque en realidad respondía perfectamente a la pregunta inicial.

Comment: Hola @Javi2EE si la respuesta responde a la pregunta inicial debieras dejarla como aceptada; eso ayudará a otros, y formular una nueva expresando en ella que la altura de las celdas debe ser variable.

Comment: Vale así lo haré si es lo correcto, era por evitar tener dos preguntas que van a ser prácticamente iguales y con casi el mismo titulo

Comment: Hola @Javi2EE, si hace la otra pregunta, hazla colocando un comentario señalando esta.

Comment: @Javi2EE Si en la nueva indicas en el título **elementos de altura variable** no habrá redundancia

Comment: @phpMyGuel, te tengo una propuesta para que tengas la respuesta completa. Independientemente de que utilices `display:flex` o `display:grid` a las reglas `.item{}` agrégale el selector `:nth-of-type(2n)` para indicar que seleccionas elementos pares y el resto a la derecha. Así solucionarías todo con independencia de que cambie de orden los elementos.

Comment: @phpMyGuel De hecho, he estado pensando responder a la pregunta, pero considero que tu respuesta está completa. Solo tienes que colocarle el selector que te indiqué en el comentario anterior. Una vez lo hayas hecho eliminaré estos comentaros. Me reservo `+1` a la espera de lo pruebes y luego lo edites.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Los de las clases `.par` e `.impar` es un requerimiento del **OP**. Este factor no lo marca su posición dentro del **DOM**, si no que cada **item** va a llegar con un valor (que puede ser par o impar) pudiendo darse el caso de que varios **items** pares vayan uno detrás del otro. (como puede verse en el **HTML** de mi respuesta).

Comment: @phpMyGuel, lo menciono por los comentarios que hacía la persona que preguntaba. Es decir, las reglas `.par {}` e `.impar {}` reemplazarla por `.item:nth-of-type(2n) {}` y `.item:nth-of-type(2n+1) {}`, ya que él quiere formar dos columnas, donde los pares van a la izquierda y los impares a la derecha.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Creo que no estás entendiendo la problemática. Sustituye mi `par` e `impar` por un `derecha` e `izquierda` para entender de lo que te hablo. Donde los itemns `izquierda` deben ir a la primera columna y los `derecha ` a la segunda.

Comment: Voy a leer de nuevo a ver.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Pero esto de par e impar es por un valor que traen estos elementos de la lista, y ese valor determina en que columna debe mostrarse, en este caso puede haber 15 elementos en la izquierda y ninguno a la derecha. Haciéndolo como comentas siempre habría el mismo número de elementos en la izquierda y la derecha.

Comment: No entiendo a donde quieres llegar. La pseudo-clase `nth-child` hace referencia a elementos respecto a su posición dentro del **DOM**. Si eres capaz de sacarle provecho en el caso que se expone, que creo que mi HTML replica, estoy encantado de aprender de tu respuesta ^^

Comment: @phpMyGuel tienes razón en la parte que me has mencionado. Sin embargo, estoy leyendo bien la pregunta para entenderla mejor. Había entendido que el OP quería a la izquierda elementos pares y a la derecha elementos impares, de allí, la pseudoclase mencionada.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Parece que el OP le valió. Según entendí ese valor llega con el elemento y por lo que veo puede ser un valor numérico cualesquiera `if(posicion%2 == 0)` por eso supongo que lo divide entre 2 para saber si debe ir a la columna de la derecha o a la izquierda. En cualquier caso es lo que yo entendí y el OP no me lo desmintió XD. Y por lo que parece el blucle podría pintar de seguido varios elementos impares o varios pares, no contrapeados par-impar.

Comment: @phpMyGuel Si, eso estuve viendo. De hecho, la respuesta es útil. Lo de **par** o **impar** pensé que tenía que ver con el **DOM**, pero no. Tienes razón en ello. De hecho, la voy a votar como útil.

Comment: @Javi2EE, fue muy importante tu aclaración y la de phpMyGuel.

Comment: Dejo aquí el enlace a la nueva pregunta por si alguien se anima con alguna solución, espero que no quede muy repetitiva la cuestión: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336312/alinear-elementos-de-altura-variable-a-izquierda-o-derecha-seg%c3%ban-un-valor