# Alinear elementos de altura variable a izquierda o derecha según un valor

Tags: html, css

Tras utilizar una [solución dada anteriormente a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336240/recorrer-una-lista-alineando-los-items-a-izquierda-o-derecha-en-funci%C3%B3n-de-su-pa) ha surgido un problema nuevo al percatarme de que estos elementos tienen altura variable. En ella decía que estoy tratando de modificar un componente existente dentro de una aplicación, la idea es que se recorre una única lista de elementos que tienen una altura variable, estos elementos tienen un campo posición, cuando la posición es left el elemento debe aparecer a la izquierda y cuando es right a la derecha. Lo explico con un trozo de código lo mas simple posible para que se entienda fácil.

```
<div class="container">
   while(!lista.isEmpty()){
     <div class="c-box if(posicion == 'right'){'c-right'}else{'c-left'}">{{item}}</div>
   }
</div>
```

Este trozo de código tras ejecutarse en el servidor y simplificándolo mucho da como resultado este:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-box c-left">1-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">2-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left" style="height:80px">3-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">4-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">5-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">6-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">7-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">8-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">9-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">10-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">11-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">12-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">13-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">14-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">15-Right</div>
</div>
```

Lo que se busca es que estos elementos se distribuyan de manera continua a izquierda y derecha sin quedar ningún hueco entre los elementos de la misma columna.

Estos son algunos de las cosas que ya se han probado y que se explican en la pregunta que hago referencia anteriormente, las añado aquí para que esta pregunta esté completa:

```css
.container{
}
.c-box{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.c-left{
    float:left;
}
.c-right{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-box c-left">1-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">2-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left" style="height:80px">3-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">4-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">5-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">6-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">7-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">8-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">9-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">10-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">11-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">12-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">13-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">14-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">15-Right</div>
</div>
```

Esta es otra prueba que genera gaps debido a los márgenes laterales

```css
.container{
    }
.c-box{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.c-left{
    float:left;
    margin-right:50%;
}
.c-right{
    float:right;
    margin-left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-box c-left">1-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">2-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">3-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">4-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">5-Right</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">6-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">7-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">8-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">9-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">10-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">11-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">12-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">13-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">14-Left</div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">15-Right</div>
</div>
```

Esta última es la respuesta que me dieron en la pregunta anterior donde no especificaba que la altura de los elementos era variable.

```css
.contenedor {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 45%;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.par {
 grid-column-start: 2;
}

.impar {
  grid-column-start: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item impar" >
    <p>Impar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item impar" style="height:100px;">
    <p>Impar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item par">
    <p>Par</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item impar">
    <p>Impar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Podría ser la solución perfecta si no fuera por la altura variable de los elementos.

Añado una imagen explicando como debería quedar y comportarse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por explicar un poco la imagen, estos campos son select y algunos de los valores de esos select hacen que se desplieguen otros campos pidiendo mas datos, esos campos que se despliegan pertenecen al mismo c-box(marcados en rectangulos negros). Por ejemplo en un momento dado alguien podría seleccionar un tipo de mecanizado y este desplegar un numero n de campos que solo deberían desplazar el campo observaciones hacia abajo pero no afectar a los elementos de la columna izquierda

Sé que utilizando 2 divs con dos columnas y recorriendo la lista dos veces este problema estaría solucionado pero no me es posible aplicar esa solución en este caso, la lista debe de recorrerse tal como aparece en el primer código, si que tengo la posibilidad de usar flex-box o cualquier solución CSS pero he realizado multitud de intentos sin ningún resultado.

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: para estar seguro ¿Quieres lograr que ambas columnas tenga la misma altura de manera que sus elementos se distribuyan uniformemente?

Comment: Hasta donde mis conocimientos alcanzan, con `grid` los elementos de una fila deben de medir lo mismo, lo que tu buscas es romper esa base. Si una columna crece sus columnas hermanas lo hacen. De todas formas creo que te estás complicando innecesariamente. ¿Ese listado de items de donde lo obtienes? ¿Lo podrías recorrer con Javascript?

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. No, en este caso lo que se busca es que queden los campos apilados desde arriba hacia abajo y que su altura la marque únicamente su contenido, no la de otros elementos.

Comment: @phpMyGuel El problema es que toda la aplicación está desarrollada en JSF y esta tecnología siempre guarda una copia exacta del DOM en el servidor que se guarda en el momento de renderizado y a su vez asigna internamente ids en función de su posición jerarquica en el DOM y da muchisimos problemas cuando se cambian posiciones de los elementos desde JS, sería preferible una solución sin JS o al menos una que no modifique su posición jerarquica en el DOM

Comment: @Javi2EE, ¿puedes colocar en tu pregunta una imagen pequeña de cómo crees que debería verse?

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Añadida

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro si esto te pueda ayudar,
intentalo, puedes agregarle clases a los inputs, para tratar de controlar la altura del los mismos,

```css
.container{
}
.c-box{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.c-box div {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 2px red
}
.c-left{
    float:left;
}
.c-right{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">1-Left</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">
      <div class="">2-Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left" >
    <div > 
      3-Left <br>
      <input placeholder="input 1"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 2"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 3"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 4"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 5"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 6"> <br>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">
      <div class="">4-Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">
      <div class="">
        5-Right <br>
      <input placeholder="input 1"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 2"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 3"> <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">6-Left</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">7-Left</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">8-Left</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">9-Left</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">10-Left</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">
      11-Left <br>
      
      <input placeholder="input 1"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 2"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 3"> <br>
      
      <input placeholder="input 1"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 2"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 3"> <br>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">12-Left</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">13-Left</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-left">
    <div class=" ">14-Left</div>    
  </div>
  <div class="c-box c-right">
    <div>
      15-Right <br>
      
      <input placeholder="input 1"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 2"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 3"> <br>
      
      <input placeholder="input 1"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 2"> <br>
      <input placeholder="input 3"> <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Nestor, bienvenido a SO y gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder pero no soluciona el problema, puedes revisar la ejecución del código y verás que quedan bloques Left en la columna de la derecha.

Comment: Huy, cierto, perdón, me emocione con el código, y no realmente todo el resutlado,